# ES File Explorer compatibility with Windows XP file sharing

Tags: windows-xp, file-sharing, android

I have read that file sharing from Windows to Android device should work with ES File Sharing. I have latest update of Windows XP and GingerBread version of Android.

Are these incompatible or what is missing when I have an exception of login failure and I am still trying anonymous login and even files are shared `to EveryOne`?

Is the problem possibly related to smb protocol because the address in properties is

```
    smb://my.very.own.ip
```

? I suppose XP makes shares with different protocol or am I right? How to connect that share then if that is the case?

**So question in short:**

has anybody got this combination to work and how?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why or how, trying to log in using credentials usually works better.